# VSCode has an issue with the : after keyframs and options

Tags: jquery

```
$('nav a[href*="#"]').on('click', function () {
    $('html, body').animate(keyframes: {
        `scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 100`
    }, options: 2000);
});

$('#up').on('click', function() {
    $('html, body').animate(keyframes: {
        scrollTop: 0
    }, options: 2000);
});
```

Comment: You need to pass an object or anything valid as first parameter of `animate()`. `keyframes:`, as well as `options:` outside of an object are not valid JavaScript.

Comment: This is how it was done in the tutorial video and there was no problem

Comment: This is invalid javascript, you have to provide an object like `{scrollTop: '...'}`